# AngularJS - evaluate a cookie in routes & template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm trying to sort out a login system using cookies so that the user's login will persist after leaving the app. I am able to set the cookie correctly, but I am unclear as to how I can use the stored cookie to limit the users access to the login screen if they are already logged in.

I think the best way to do this would be within the routes. This is what my file currently looks like:

```
var routes = angular.module('we365', ['rcForm', 'ngCookie', 'ngCookies']);
routes.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {

        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'

    })

    .when('/', {// get digest view

        templateUrl: 'views/getDigest.html',
        controller: 'GetDigestCtrl'

    })

    .when('/artifact/:artifact_id', {// single artifact view

        templateUrl: 'views/artifact.html',
        controller: 'artifactCtrl'

    })

    .otherwise({

        redirectTo: '/'

    });

});
```

Also, i'd like to hide the 'login' button from the parent view so that the user isn't able to click on it. This is what the view looks like now:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header col col-lg-12">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <a href="/#/login/" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary button-login">Login</a>
        <a href="/#/" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary button-getDigest">Load Digest Data</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One method would be to use the "resolve" method before loading the new  view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, I have two that are my favorite:

**1) Check on route change**

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.run(function($rootScope, myLoginService) {
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
  if (!myLoginService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
    $location.path('/login');
  }
});
```

You can replace the `isUserLogged` for a mapper service that receives where the user wants to go; if the user has the proper privileges (either stored within a cookie or local storage in the form of a token), then let the route succeed. Otherwise, show an error, or route him to wherever you want. In my case, the `myLoginService` checks for a localStorage.

**2) Any data request to a server has a token included to headers; failed requests (401) are intercepted and stored, while the user is redirected**

This one is more for CRUD apps and not necessarily for routing, but the concept is simple: a user A can perform N actions as long as he/she has the privileges to do so; if he tries to perform an action (or M actions) that he's not allowed, then the request is intercepted and queued in order to ask him to authenticate with a user that CAN do those actions

```
.factory('securityInterceptor', ['$injector', 'securityRetryQueue', function($injector, queue) {
  return function(promise) {
    // Intercept failed requests
    return promise.then(null, function(originalResponse) {
      if(originalResponse.status === 401) {
        // The request bounced because it was not authorized - add a new request to the retry queue
        promise = queue.pushRetryFn('unauthorized-server', function retryRequest() {
          // We must use $injector to get the $http service to prevent circular dependency
          return $injector.get('$http')(originalResponse.config);
        });
      }
      return promise;
    });
  };
}]);
```

Again, this is for more "data like" requests and not necessarily for routing. This was stolen from the [AngularJS](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/security/interceptor.js) sample app. You should check it for more examples.

Comment: @jjprezaguinaga - is it possible to test for the existance of a cookie on the template level?

Comment: Not that I know of, and I would recommend against it. All business logic should be dealt in your controller.

Comment: How do I go about showing/hiding links in a navigation, for a login/log out button?

Comment: You can use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` in cases that you don't want your entire UI being defined in a controller. So for instance `<button ng-show="myLoginService.isLoggedIn()> Logout </button>`